# deleting a user local profile in Win 7

Tags: windows-7, user-profiles

Does deleting a user local profile in win 7, also delete MS Office files stored in the My Documents folder on C drive? I deleted a local profile and now user calims he is missing files in C: My Documents.

Comment: By deleting a user local profile do you mean manually removing the user's profile directory, if you do mean that, then of course it would delete the files in `My Documents` considering that folder is a sub-directory of the user profile directory.

Comment: Not exactly. I used the System Properties Applet, rt click Computer>properties>advanced tab> user profile. Would that also remove files in the folder? Documents Folder was still there, but contained only 2 files when the user logged back on. She claims there were many office files in there. Shadow copy got them back, but I need to know for the future. Thanks!

Comment: Removing the User does not normally delete that user's profile directory.

Answer (score 2):

The local user profile on the C drive will be located at C:\Users\Username and the user's My documents folder will be located at C\Users\Username\Documents. Hence, deleting the local user profile will remove that user's Documents folder.